# Matlab code to .mex using code package

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I would like to optimize a function written in Matlab by converting the code to C\C++. The result should be callable from within matlab, as it is a small part of a larger matlab code.

For example, converting my function to C code wrapped in a .mex file would work.
I heard matlab coder package can help with that.

As I am unfamiliar with this package, what is the quickest way to achieve this?

Comment: It depends of the complexity of your code... Do you have a matab coder licence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a license for MATLAB Coder, then, yes, that is the correct package to use. The function you're looking for is [`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/coder/ref/codegen.html). There are restrictions on what can be used in code generation: to see if your function meets those restrictions, add the tag `%#codegen` to the beginning of your function as shown below

```
function foo(bar) %#codegen
    <your code here>
```

and open the function file in the MATLAB editor. The tag tells the editor to check that the code complies with the rules for code generation. Once the editor shows that your code complies with those rules, generating the mex file may be as easy as

```
>> codegen foo
```

which would generate a mex-file, `foo_mex` in the current folder. For your particular function you may need to use some of the optional arguments for [`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/coder/ref/codegen.html) to generate the mex-file properly.

Comment: Thanks. I have a license. Can I give this mex to someone without a license? (possibly running an older Matlab version before this package was out)

Comment: AFAIK a license is not required to use the mex-file. Mex-files are architecture specific, however, as you can see from their file extensions, so you need to be aware of the architecture of the other person's machine. As to older versions of MATLAB, I imagine that the basic libraries the mex-files link to don't change that much, but you'd need to check if it works for your application.